# Can/Should I Linqify this foreach/if/foreach/if/invoke code?

Tags: c#, linq, observer-pattern

Code I think can be Linq:

```
    foreach (var key in _dic.Keys) // for each observed key
        if (_changedKeys.Contains(key)) // if it changed
            foreach (var item in _dic[key]) // then for each observer
                if (_webSitePage.Session[key] != null) // , as long as the value is something
                    item(_webSitePage.Session[key]); // call the registered delegate
```

In context of surrounding code:

```
public class WebSiteContext
{
    private WebSitePage _webSitePage;

    internal void SetSessionValue<T>(string key, T value)
    {
        object current = _webSitePage.Session[key];
        if (current != null && current.Equals(value)) return;
        _webSitePage.Session[key] = value;
        _changedKeys.Add(key);
    }

    Dictionary<string, List<Action<object>>> _dic = new Dictionary<string, List<Action<object>>>();

    List<string> _changedKeys = new List<string>();

    internal void WhenSessionValueChanges(string key, Action<object> action)
    {
        if (!_dic.ContainsKey(key)) _dic[key] = new List<Action<object>>(); // create on demand
        _dic[key].Add(action);
    }

    internal void PageLoadComplete()
    {
        foreach (var key in _dic.Keys) // for each observed key
            if (_changedKeys.Contains(key)) // if it changed
                foreach (var item in _dic[key]) // then for each observer
                    if (_webSitePage.Session[key] != null) // , as long as the value is something
                        item(_webSitePage.Session[key]); // call the registered delegate

    }
}

public class WebSitePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public WebSitePage()
    {
        this.WebSiteContext = new WebSiteContext(this);
    }

    public WebSiteContext WebSiteContext { get; set; }

    protected override void OnLoadComplete(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoadComplete(e);
        this.WebSiteContext.PageLoadComplete();
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to ask a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *could* be changed to LINQ, but since you are calling `item(...)` for its side-effects, I think using LINQ here is inappropriate and a `foreach` loop is better.

You could however write something like this:

```
 foreach (var key in _dic.Keys.Where(key => _changedKeys.Contains(key))
 {
     foreach (var item in _dic[key])
     {
         var value = _webSitePage.Session[key];
         if (value != null)
         {
             item(value);
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var keys = from key in _dic.Keys
           where _changedKeys.Contains(key) && _webSitePage.Session[key] != null
           from item in _dic[key]
           select item;

foreach (var key in keys)
    item(_webSitePage.Session[key]);
```

EDIT:

The above is horribly wrong.  Apologies.  I was intent on using query comprehension to answer the question.  Here's an attempt:

```
var tuples = from key in _dic.Keys
       where _changedKeys.Contains(key) && _webSitePage.Session[key] != null
       from item in _dic[key]
       select new { key, item };

foreach (var t in tuples)
    t.item(_webSitePage.Session[t.key]);
```

Comment: item does not exist in the second loop

Comment: @Mark Byers.  Excellent question.  It was a massive copy-and-paste fail.  Corrected code appended.

Answer (score 2):

```
var keys = _dic.Keys.Where(key => _changedKeys.Contains(key) && 
                                  (_webSitePage.Session[key] != null));
foreach (var key in keys)
  foreach (var item in _dic[key])
    item(_webSitePage.Session[key]);
```

(the second test does not need to be in the inner foreach loop unless item modifies _webSitePage.Session)

Answer (score 2):

This shortens it a little. Note that I moved the _webSitePage check up because it does not depend on the value of `item`:

```
foreach (var kvp in _dic.Where(kvp => !_changedKeys.Contains(kvp.Key) && _webSitePage.Session[kvp.Key] != null))
    foreach (var item in kvp.Values) // then for each observer
        item(_webSitePage.Session[key]); // call the registered delegate
```

Comment: Agreed, but I never claimed it was an improvement on the whole, nor did the original poster seem to want only sure improvements. I was just showing the possibility of "Linqifying" the code, as the original poster requested.

Comment: @Platinium Azure, theoritically it could depend on it if item modifies _webSitePage.Session